# How to remove custom Rviz Plugin

Tags: ros, c++, rviz, ros-melodic, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created rviz plugin following [these](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html) tutorials . However I was wondering how can I remove them. I couldnt find any documentation/guidelines for it. Please provide any hints / suggestions.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340839/how-to-remove-custom-rviz-plugin/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2019-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I couldnt find any documentation/guidelines for it.

I could imagine this is because it essentially comes down to removing either the package hosting the custom plugin from the workspace, or removing the plugin `export` from the package manifest of that same package.

Have you tried this?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2020-01-02**:
It works. Just had to remove export tag from package.xml. Thanks alot